# Increase number of clicks on each collection view cell and display them in each cell

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView displaying a UITextField inside each row. The number of rows may be dynamic, and what I want is to display the *number of times* the specific cell is being clicked and display count on each textfield simultaneously.

I have tried setting a variable for number of clicks and I've tracked each index-path so the count is increased but,

I'm *unable to increase their own value on their own cell*.

Comment: Why would someone have given a minus vote for this question ???? So, @aashish wants a logic as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this right after you increment the variable:

```
collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPath)
```

Comment: I surely did that, as I mentioned.

Comment: Did you try adding a print("something") in that function to check if it's triggered?

Answer (score -1):

> I only have this logic maybe it would help you a little bit, I may
>   provide you with code after I convert my logic to code.

If you have already stored the number of clicks then you must make an array to append the cell which has been clicked and filter the `indexpath.row` that you will append in this array which you'll get in `didSelectRowAt`.

You need to filter them such that, if the selected cell has previously been appended in the array it needs to be removed from that index and appended to the last index of the same array.

So that you can access the array of your clicked row, to show them on each of their cells textfield.